# In what directory lies the local storage of a webview on macOS?

Tags: macos, webview, local-storage, wkwebview

In other words how can I delete an app's webview data without having access to the web developer tools of the webview? Where is it stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching through my `~/Library` folder I stumbled upon it:

A webview of an application with the package id `your.package.id` will store localstorage, cookies, etc. in `/Users/your-username/Library/WebKit/your.package.id` (where your-username needs to be replaced by whatever your username is ;-).

So deleting this directory will clear all data created by the webview.

I run macOS Mojave, but my guess is this won't change often.